# How to pass array data to state from a form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new on react js
I have this state:

```
state = {
    protocol_number: this.year.toString()
        +Math.floor(Math.pow(10,5)
        +Math.random()*Math.pow(9, 6)).toString(),
    ticket_date: this.full_date,
    company_name: '',
    nameError: '',
    trading_name: '',
    request_type: '',
    ticket_description: '',
    isOpen: false,
    image: null,
    product_list: []
};
```

this is beeing submited to the API this way:

```
handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ addItemModal: false });

    const data = new FormData();

    data.append('protocol_number', this.state.protocol_number);
    data.append('ticket_date', this.state.ticket_date);
    data.append('company_name', this.state.company_name);
    data.append('trading_name', this.state.trading_name);
    data.append('request_type', this.state.request_type);
    data.append('ticket_description', this.state.ticket_description);
    data.append('image', this.state.image);

    await api.post('new_ticket.php', data);
    console.log(this.state);
    this.props.history.push('/done');
};
```

How can I get the product list like an array to submit everything together?
Here is a example of the deployed app: [heroku](https://am-devolucoes.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.

> As with regular form data, you can append multiple values with the same name. For example (and being compatible with PHP's naming conventions by adding [] to the name):

```
formData.append('userpic[]', myFileInput.files[0], 'chris1.jpg');
formData.append('userpic[]', myFileInput.files[1], 'chris2.jpg');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append